# Where to choose a shapefile for appending?

Tags: qgis

I want to append several shapefiles in QGIS. The ftools 0.6.1 add-on is installed.

But under Vektor>Datenmanagement-Werkzeuge>Shapedateien zu einer zusammenführen (=append shapefiles) is only the possiblility to choose the Eingabedatei (input file) and the Ausgabedatei (output file) but not a further Datei (file) for the append itself?
(Even though there are  several shapefiles in the same folder)

//Furthermore the icon "In neue Projektion exportieren" (export to new projection) is also not appearing under the: Vektor>Datenmanagement-Werkzeuge? Do I need a further add-on?//

Has anyone an idea why I can't choose a shapefile for the appending?

Thanks in advance!
phil

Answer (score 3):

In my English version of QGIS 1.7.4 (with fTools 0.6.1) the tool is called "Merge Shapefiles".

In the dialog you select the "Input directory" (not a single file but a directory of files) and and "Output shapefile". --> **All Shapefiles** within the selected folder will be merged.

Sounds like the translation is a bit off in German GUI.

---

Update:

ad. "In neue Projektion exportieren" (export to new projection)

The function was redundant and has been removed. You can export o new projection using "Save as ..." from layer list context menu.

Comment: thanks, ...yes, that seems to be the same as "Shapedateien zu einer zusammenführen", but I can't choose a file which has to be appended to the input file? I can only choose an input file which then is simular as the output file (=Ausgabedatei in German).

Comment: Put all files you want to merge into one folder and select that folder as "input directory".

Comment: :) thanks a lot! like that it works! The German translation is not clear in that way, because the GUI is asking for a "Eingabedatei" which is a file an not a folder. Thank you a lot for the precision! Best regards phil

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to do it in QGIS (although I think it should be possible) but why don't you use the commandline with ogr2ogr:
http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

You could use the append switch to append shapes to your inputfile. It should be possible to name a folder with all your shapes to append. Alternatively you could use a loop, like (depending on your OS, here Windows): for %s in (Folder_with_shapes_to append*.shp) do ogr2ogr -append -f "ESRI Shapefile" shape_to_append_to %s